# Mysql Stored Procedure creation with TRANSACTION problem

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

i have to create such a procedure but i get errors
i have solve it just by removing BEGIN and END in other procedures but this one has TRANSACTION and i cant find the solution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_device_post_device_status (IN deviceID int(11), IN zone int(11), IN stat int(11)) 
BEGIN 
    START TRANSACTION
    UPDATE device_statuses
    SET is_last_one = 0
    WHERE id_device = deviceID
      AND is_last_one = 1
      AND zoneNo = zone;
   INSERT INTO device_statuses (id_device, zoneNo, status, is_last_one)
    VALUES (deviceID, zone, stat, 1);
    commit
END;
```

it returns :

```
SQL query: Copy


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_device_post_device_status (IN deviceID int(11), IN zone int(11), IN stat int(11)) 
BEGIN 
    START TRANSACTION
    UPDATE device_statuses
    SET is_last_one = 0
    WHERE id_device = deviceID
      AND is_last_one = 1
      AND zoneNo = zone
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE device_statuses
    SET is_last_one = 0
    WHERE id_device = deviceID
' at line 4
```

Answer (score -1):

i solved it in this way

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_device_post_device_status`(IN deviceID int(11), IN zone int(11), IN stat int(11))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

```
UPDATE device_statuses
SET is_last_one = 0
WHERE id_device = deviceID
  AND is_last_one = 1
  and zoneNo = zone;

insert into device_statuses (id_device, zoneNo, status, is_last_one)
VALUES (deviceID, zone, stat, 1);
commit;
```

end$$
DELIMITER ;